# Number format en laravel

Tags: laravel-5

Cómo puedo hacer el numberformat de php en laravel para un input tipo texto dos decimales?

```
{!!Form::text(number_format(campoaformatear,2,'.',',')null,['class'=>'form-control'])!!}
```

Answer (score 2):

Me parece que deberías comprobar con un shorthand de  if/else, si existe $campo, para evitar un error al tratar de formatear un null

```
{!! Form::text(
($campo) ? number_format($campo, 2, '.', ',') : ''
, null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Answer (score 1):

La sintaxis que utilizas debería funcionar sin problema, aunque te falta una coma (,), sin embargo no creo que le quieras asignar un nombre al campo que incluya dos decimales.

```
{!! Form::text(number_format($campo, 2, '.', ','), null, ['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

Comment: Desde que formule la pregunta lo hice mal, lo siento, en realidad debería de quedar así {!!Form::text('campo',number_format(null, 2, '.', ','),['class'=>'form-control'])!!} ya que el numberFormat se le pone es al valor (en este caso el null) y no al 'campo' que es el nombre del input

Comment: Funciona ahora o aún no? aunque claramente no podrías darle formato a null.

Comment: Tendrías que explicar mejor que es lo que pretendes hacer, con un ejemplo.