# Laravel: Separar numeros despues de 3 cifras con coma o punto

Tags: php, laravel

Quiero que cuando el precio o el campo que sea pase de 3 cifras se separen con comas por ejemplo:
Si el resultado de una consulta es = 1200 quiero que se me muestre asi, 1,200

Comment: Revisa si esto te sirve https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18277/number-format-en-laravel

Answer (score 1):

**Buenas,**
 utiliza number_format el cual formatea un número con los millares agrupados

**Nota:**

Esta función acepta uno, dos, o cuatro parámetros (no tres):

Si solo se proporciona un parámetro, number será formateado sin decimales, pero con una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan dos parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como se hayan definido en decimals colocando un punto (".") delante, y una coma (",") entre cada grupo de millares.

Si se proporcionan los cuatro parámetros, number será formateado con tantos decimales como hayamos definido en decimals, dec_point sustituirá al punto (".") como seperador de los decimales y el separador por defecto de los millares, la coma (","), será sustituida por thousands_sep.

**Ejemplo:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php
echo number_format (1000000) ;
?>

</body>
</html>
```

**Salida :** 1,000,000

Comment: Solo recuerda que la sintaxis debería ser para blade pues el usa Laravel

Comment: `@php {{-- php code here --}} @endphp`  , solo le puse un ejemplo en php.

Comment: No hay necesidad de usar @php Checa la respuesta del enlace que marque como duplicada arriba

Comment: Mil gracias funciono perfectamente