# ¿Cómo agrego separador de millares?

Tags: php

tengo el siguiente código php laravel como mostrar el . (punto) separador de millares en las cifras.... son cifras de millones.

```
 <td>$ {{ $transf->coparticipacion }} </td>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Number format en laravel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/18277/number-format-en-laravel)

Answer (score 1):

En PHP tienes la función [number_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php), si lees la documentación te dice que su forma de usar es la siguiente:

```
number_format(float $num , int $decimals = 0 , string|null $decimal_separator = "." , string|null $thousands_separator = ",")
```

Donde **$num** es el número a formatear, **$decimals** es la cantidad de decimales que se desea mostrar, **$decimal_separator** es el separador de decimales y **$thousands_separator** el separador de miles o cientos. Entonces si quieres mostrar 2 decimales, con un punto en separador de miles y con coma como separador de decimales, solo debes hacer:

```
number_format(2541.32, 2, ',', '.');
```

Eso te debe mostrar: ***2.541,32***